# How do I setup OneDrive Filepicker v8 for Business/Sharepoint with Javascript? (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I already have put some hours into the setup of the OneDrive FilePicker v8 for Javascript for personal users to access their *personal* OneDrive files. Now I want to do the same for users with *business/school* accounts. I manage to get to the *My Files* part, but I cannot access any Sharepoint folder/site. I am not sure whether my lies with

- The app configuration (AAD)
- The javascript implementation
- The configuration/permissions of the individual Sharepoint

The error I receive is `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException`, and I struggle to find any meaningful documentation for it.

[image: Error screenshot of the Sharepoint OneDrive FilePicker]

---

This is the AAD configuration:

```json
{
    "id": "***",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "***",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2023-01-17T13:20:32Z",
    "description": null,
    "certification": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": "https://***.com/app/tos",
        "support": null,
        "privacy": "https://***.com/app/privacy",
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": "https://aadcdn.msftauthimages.net/c1c6b6c8-v-6zmda-jxeuzcj5pwn1sghjyu3gaqcdbwxfx543nak/appbranding/caofuabptruma-iurozspazfz7p4ilc95fi3qyhjlu0/1033/bannerlogo?ts=638095585782399340",
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "File Picker (SharePoint)",
    "notes": null,
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "***.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://localhost",
            "type": "Spa"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://localhost",
            "type": "Spa"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://***.com/onedrive/search",
            "type": "Spa"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [<see next image>],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": "https://***.com",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

With following scopes (`requiredResourceAccess`):

[image: Scopes of the AAD]

And the browser implementation (reduced to the minimum to reproduce the error):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>File Picker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-lg pt-3">
    <h3 class="d-flex align-items-center"><span>OneDrive File Picker</span></h3>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary" id="launchPicker">Pick from OneDrive</button></div>
    <iframe class="w-100 mt-3" id="iframe" frameborder="0" style="min-height:600px;resize:vertical;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.19.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"
    nonce="392b4bdf6481a24edf09d81187872ce7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" nonce="392b4bdf6481a24edf09d81187872ce7">
    const SUB = "***"; // Test user
    const REDIRECT_URI = `https://***.com/onedrive/search` // Test redirect url
    const BASE_URL = `https://***-my.sharepoint.com/` // Test url

    const msalParams =
    {
      auth:
      {
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations", // Full directory URL, in the form of https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>
        clientId: "***", // 'Application (client) ID' of app registration in Azure portal - this value is a GUID
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
      },
    }

    const app = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalParams);

    const redirectResponse = app.handleRedirectPromise();

    async function getToken() {
      let accessToken = "";

      const account = await app.getAccountByLocalId(SUB);

      if (await redirectResponse !== null) {
        // Acquire token silent success
        accessToken = redirectResponse.accessToken;
      }
      else {
        authParams =
        {
          scopes: [`${BASE_URL}.default`],
          account: account
        };

        try {
          // see if we have already the idtoken saved
          const resp = await app.acquireTokenSilent(authParams);
          accessToken = resp.accessToken;
        }
        catch (e) {
          // per examples we fall back to popup
          return app.acquireTokenRedirect(authParams);
        }
      }


      return accessToken;
    }

    // the options we pass to the picker page through the querystring
    const params =
    {
      sdk: "8.0",
      entry:
      {
        oneDrive:
        {
          files: {},
        }
      },
      authentication: {},
      messaging:
      {
        origin: window.location.href,
        channelId: "27"
      },
      typesAndSources:
      {
        mode: "files",
        pivots:
        {
          oneDrive: true,
          recent: true,
          sharedLibraries: true,
        },
        //- filters: ".csv,.xlsx"
      },
      selection:
      {
        mode: "pick"
      },
      commands:
      {
        pick:
        {
          label: "Import"
        },
        close:
        {
          label: "Close"
        }
      }
    };

    async function launchPicker(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      //- win = window.open("", "Picker", "width=800,height=600")
      const frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
      const win = frame.contentWindow;

      const authToken = await getToken();

      const queryString = new URLSearchParams(
        {
          filePicker: JSON.stringify(params),
        });

      const url = `${BASE_URL}_layouts/15/FilePicker.aspx?${queryString}`;

      const form = win.document.createElement("form");
      form.setAttribute("action", url);
      form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
      win.document.body.append(form);

      const input = win.document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("type", "hidden")
      input.setAttribute("name", "access_token");
      input.setAttribute("value", authToken);
      form.appendChild(input);

      form.submit();

      window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        if (event.source && event.source === win) {
          const message = event.data;

          if (message.type === "initialize" && message.channelId === params.messaging.channelId) {
            port = event.ports[0];

            port.addEventListener("message", messageListener);

            port.start();

            port.postMessage(
              {
                type: "activate",
              });
          }
        }
      });
    }

    async function messageListener(message) {
      switch (message.data.type) {
        case "notification":
          console.log(`notification: ${message.data}`);
          break;

        case "command":
          port.postMessage(
            {
              type: "acknowledge",
              id: message.data.id,
            });

          const command = message.data.data;

          switch (command.command) {
            case "authenticate":
              // getToken is from scripts/auth.js
              const token = await getToken();

              if (typeof token !== "undefined" && token !== null) {
                port.postMessage(
                  {
                    type: "result",
                    id: message.data.id,
                    data:
                    {
                      result: "token",
                      token,
                    }
                  });
              }
              else {
                console.error(`Could not get auth token for command: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`);
              }

              break;

            case "close":
              history.back();
              break;

            case "pick":
              console.log(`Picked: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`);

              port.postMessage(
                {
                  type: "result",
                  id: message.data.id,
                  data: {
                    result: "success",
                  },
                });

              console.info(command)

              break;

            default:
              console.warn(`Unsupported command: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`, 2);

              port.postMessage(
                {
                  result: "error",
                  error:
                  {
                    code: "unsupportedCommand",
                    message: command.command
                  },
                  isExpected: true,
                });
              break;
          }

          break;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("launchPicker").onclick = launchPicker;

    // Check the token directly and reload when no access token acquirable
    getToken().then((accessToken) => {
      if (!accessToken) {
        console.info("Something went wrong acquiring a token, reloading the page and try again!")
        window.location.reload();
      }
    })</script>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you have any joy with this @Miaucl?  We're having the exact same issue.

Comment: Not really, I raised a ticket but got no response until now... @WayneIvory

Comment: Do you mean you raised a ticket with Microsoft and just got a response @Miaucl?

Comment: @WayneIvory No, I raised it in parallel with creating this question, but no response from them...

Answer (score 1):

We've got exactly the same error when testing the picker for our Sharepoint installation, tracked it down to Sharepoint site rename.

Sharepoint / File picker requests tokens for old Sharepoint site name when navigating those share libraries, so you have those invalid audience errors then picked tries to load list of files.

Add tracing to authenticate command and check base url. It will be for previous site name. Please be aware that picker calls authenticate multiple times.

The best way to validate that is to go directly to your Onedrive for Business website, https://{company}-my.sharepoint.com/, and check quick access links at the bottom left. If they are broken for you, then it's not you code, it's just rename artifact.

It seems be be unfixable on the picker side, as MS have that listed as "No action is available" at [image] See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name#medium-impact

Answer (score 0):

Remove `sharedLibraries: true`, in the `pivots` object and try. Recently there is a update in the V8. It is obtaining both sharePoint token and OneDrive token initially and use it according.